# Successfully subscribed to event notification from CTS Surveyor facial detection server but face events are not coming

Tags: c#, machine-learning, computer-vision, peoplepicker, facial-identification

I have subscribed to the CTS Surveyor's Web Socket service as per the integration guide http://caerustech-solutions.com/demo/User_Guide.pdf , and received back the {"events":[{"event":"connected"}]}, however I there are no "people" events that are coming.

The following is my code:

```
webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
```

and then I am listening on the socket like this:

```
var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
```

As per the documentation, I am supposed to be getting faces_found events, but that is not happening. Can anyone tell me what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DEFAULT_READ_FACES and DEFAULT_COUNT_PEOPLE flags in the config.ini file? As per their doc, you can either set them to True to be always available, or enable people/faces feature through the control API, such as http://localhost:5000/enable_feature?feature=face

Comment: Thank you for the answer roagnarok, I indeed had configuration with face feature being turned off